# Mongoose - Schema for Subdocuments of unknown size

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a schema in Mongoose for a set of JSON files being generated by an outside program. Let's say, the program creates JSON files with varying number of subdocuments (i.e. a user can create between 1-8 records).

How do I structure the Schema to handle the variable parameters?

```
"Results": {
"Raw": {
  "FileName": "Excel-150101",
  "FilePath": "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Excel-150101.csv"
},
"Data": [
  {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Conc": 10.1,
    "Units": "ng/ml"
  },
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Conc": 2.1,
    "Units": "ng/ml"
  },
  /*... (Variable amount of additional data here) */
]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think what you are looking for is this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  Raw: {
    FileName: String,
    FilePath:  String
  },
  Data: [{ Name: String, Conc: Number, Units: String }]
});
```

Notice the `Data` field is an array, which would let you add any amount of data in it.

You can check [Mongoose Schemas v3.8.23](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) for more information.

Comment: For anyone else looking for it in the documentation, see the example:   
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }]